# Could not able to click the link from the container

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

hi all thanks for reading my question. I tried to automate some of my work. I tried to get the path of Add button using xpath finder I found three links below. I tried to click on the add button but its not working. The curser is in the first name box. Below my code is there. Please help me to click the Add button.

```
[![#driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div\[@class='content col-center'\]/..//input\[@name='Add'\]\]").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/div\[@id='contWrapper'\]/div\[@id='ContContent'\]/div\[@id='pageContent'\]/form\[@id='viewAllSales'\]/div\[@class='container'\]/div\[@class='content col-center'\]/div\[5\]/..//input\[@name='Add'\]").click()
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//input\[@name='Add'\])\[1\]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try applying some external **[`delay`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)**? I think maybe the `click` is happening before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input class="button" name="Add" type="button"> is not clickable at point (807,507) because another element <div id="statusbar"> obscures it
--- I am getting above error

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the XPath you're using to locate the "Add" button is accurate. It should uniquely identify the button element. If there are multiple matching elements, you might be clicking the wrong one.

Explicit Wait: Use explicit waits to ensure that the element is present and clickable before you attempt to click it. An implicit wait of 60 seconds, as shown in your code, might not be sufficient for the page to load.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your_website_url_here")

try:
    # Locate the "Add" button
    add_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Add']")

    # Scroll to the "Add" button
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(add_button).perform()

    # Click the "Add" button
    add_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

driver.quit()
```

Note :
If the "Add" button is inside an iframe, you need to switch to that iframe before interacting with the button. You can use driver.switch_to.frame() for this purpose.

Comment: i tried above code and getting this reply. selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input class="button" name="Add" type="button"> is not clickable at point (807,507) because another element <div id="statusbar"> obscures it

Comment: The ElementClickInterceptedException occurs when another element on the page is obstructing the element you are trying to click. In this case, it appears that the "Add" button is obscured by the <div id="statusbar"> element.

To deal with this situation, you can use a combination of actions like scrolling or hovering to ensure that the "Add" button becomes clickable I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Solved the above using the above code. Thank you so much everyone for help.

```
try:
    # Locate the "Add" button
    add_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Add']")
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    actions.move_to_element(add_button).perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    actions.move_to_element(add_button).click().perform()

except:
    print("The element is not clickable")
```